# Why do I get a blank desktop upon login?

Tags: login-screen, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I shut down my computer for the week-end and when I came back this morning, it wouldn't open my session.

Ubuntu starts and display the session log in menu. When I choose the Guest session every thing works fine. But when I try with my own session, I am blocked on an empty screen (just the default Ubuntu wallpaper).

- I tried with every login option (Classic, Classic[no effects], Unity, Unit 2D), the prblem is the same with every one of them.
- I was on Ubuntu 11.10, and upgraded to 12.04. The problem still occures.
- If I log in the console (`Ctr+Alt+F1`), it works...

Do you have any suggestion ? Maybe start my session from the console, or any other idea you could have...